# Loadbalancer breaks assets in Laravel4

Tags: php, nginx, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I've got a problem with Laravel4. I've created simple website for partners, based on Laravel4 Bootstrap Starter ( https://github.com/andrew13/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site ). The problem is that site is located in two diffrent psyhical servers with loadbalancer in front of them. Basset generates CSS&JS files in public/assets/compiled, but i've got diffrent checksums on diffrent servers.

So, it sometimes loads CSS files from server1, sometimes from server2. When HTML is generated by S1 & CSS files by S2 there's a 404 error.

You can see example of this problem here:
http://affiliate.pirrit.com (refresh it few times)

Comment: Ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how basset works, but if you can output the file name (not the HTML, the actual file) without the hash, you can use [H5BP's rewrite rule](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/master/.htaccess#L506) to use the hash in HTML and route to actual file. This gives you the benefit of cache-busting without the pitfalls you're experiencing of being behind a load balancer.

There's an [nginx version](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/blob/master/conf/cache-busting.conf) also as your server (or at least your load balancer) appears to be nginx.

Lastly, this if off-topic,

1. Have you made sure that your sessions are "sticky" (or made sure your sessions are persistent on a central storage?). Load balancing tends to mess that up unless care is taken
2. Every web request has the potential to look like its coming from the same user (aka your load balancer) unless the user's useragent/IP address is passed through to your origin servers.

Just mentioning that in case you run into it as well. It's completely off-topic to your Basset issue. It's something I've run into a bunch.